# Will Gruff work with other repos than AllegroGraph?

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, allegrograph

Seems that Gruff only works with AllegroGraph.

I've watched a presentation where it says it can connect to SPARQL endpoints, but with a lot of limitations, and to contact Franz to remove some of these limitations.

Comment: See the "New in version 5.2" section on [this page](https://franz.com/agraph/gruff/) and also [release notes](https://franz.com/agraph/gruff/release-history.lhtml) for version 5.2.1...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Stanislav! Here's the text for reference "The new command "File | Connect to SPARQL Endpoint" allows browsing any SPARQL endpoint directly, without using an AllegroGraph store. The new child menu "Global Options | SPARQL Endpoints" contains options that are specific to SPARQL endpoints, mostly to disable certain capabilities by default that may typically be too slow for an endpoint; in particular, label properties are not displayed by default with endpoints, but they can be. Most Gruff functionality is available with endpoints, though some menu commands that are not available (such as path-finding) will be grayed out and inactive when using an endpoint". I hope to try it out soon.